# Frailty or median values in my cox proportional hazards model?

Tags: r, cox-model, median, proportional-hazards, frailty

I am analysing data of woodpecker-made holes and I am interested in seeing what covariates and to what degree affect the survival of these holes (otherwise known as cavities). However, I encounter the complication that quite many trees contain multiple holes and thus, if the tree falls (which is the most common cause of a cavity death) it takes all these cavities in that tree down. Therefore, I wanted to have the tree's identity number as a random effect in my model. Thus I added frailty(tree_id) to my R script in the coxph function.

Another type of correction that I applied for more than one cavity in a single tree was to only keep 1 cavity and give it the median "age" value of all these cavities that were present in the particular single tree. The covariates that I test for do not change per cavity, but rather per tree.

Which approach is correct, if any?

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Alwin

Comment: Are there other causes of cavity death other than a tree falling down? If yes, you may be in a competing risks type of setting.  Also, can you clarify how you assess "survival of cavity"? If you don't know the exact time when the cavity first appeared on the tree, you may be dealing with both left and right censoring.

Comment: I also have a cause-specific hazards model for the 2 different causes of cavity death (the other being destruction of the cavity from different sources combined). I also have 1 general model however that combines all causes of cavity death. Cavity survival is assessed visually in the field. We have only included newly made cavities so we only have right censoring.